# How to change the delimiter from ',' to 'Ç' in a .txt file using bigquery command?

Tags: linux, unix, google-bigquery

i have a .txt file named fileids.txt which has the data in below format,

```
FILENAME,FILEID
CFM,101
CFG,102
CFH,103
```

I wanted to convert the delimiter in this file from , to Ç (Cidella) using a bq command or an unix/linux command. is this possible?

Comment: Hi, welcome. If the answer helped you, be sure to upvote it and /or mark as accepted. You can find useful info in the  [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about bigquery, but using `sed` in linux this is trivial:

```
$ cat fields.txt
FILENAME,FILEID
CFM,101
CFG,102
CFH,103
$ sed -i 's/,/Ç/' fields.txt
$ cat fields.txt
FILENAMEÇFILEID
CFMÇ101
CFGÇ102
CFHÇ103
```